# Gitlab. How to provide values for property "options" from file include?

Tags: bash, gitlab, include, gitlab-ci, pipeline

For the past two days, I've been struggling with my issue. I've tried several scripts, but none of them seem to work. I would like to include a file from a different location in my .gitlab-ci.yaml file and dynamically pass values to the 'options' key through that file.  It should look like this.

```
variables:
DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT:
    value: "dev"
    options: 
      - value1
      - value2
      - value3
```

I want the values to be enclosed within the file from which I'm doing the include.
Is this achievable? Please provide any tips or assistance. Below, I'm sharing the content of my .gitlab-ci.yaml file:

```
  - project: 'path/to/file'
    ref: dev
    file: '.template_api.yaml'
  - project: 'path/to/file'
    ref: dev
    file: 'deploy_config.yaml'
  - project: 'path/to/file'
    ref: dev
    file: 'options_env.yaml'
  - project: 'path/to/file'
    ref: dev
    file: 'options_branch.yaml'
    
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "pipeline"'

before_script:
  - |
    options_env=$(cat options-env.yaml | yq e '.options_env[]' -)
    options_env_string="options:\n$(echo "$options_env" | sed 's/^/  - /')"

variables:
  DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT:
    value: "dev"
    options: 
      - ${cat options_env_list.yaml}
    description: "The deployment target. Change this variable to 'test' or 'prod' if needed."
  DEPLOY_FROM_BRANCH:
    value: "main"
    options: 
      - ${cat options_env_list.yaml}
    description: "The deployment target. Change this variable to 'test' or 'prod' if needed."

stages:
 - deploy
```

Thanks for your help.